# Creating a Favorites List using expandable list view that can create groups? Android

Tags: android

I've been searching for a way to create a favorites list.  Something like the expandable list view but instead of having fixed groups it should allow the user to add groups he desires.  I use a `HashMap<String, List<String>>` for storing the subgroups and their Group's name. I also use a text file to load stored groups and subgroups.

Is it possible to reuse a `List<String>` to enter values into the HashMap.  My multiple attempts have failed so I was wondering if there is a possible work around.  This is basically what I did for my last attempt:

```
myList.add("Carrot");
myList.add("Cabbage");

myHash.put("Group1", myList);
myList.clear();

myList.add("Orange");
myList.add("Apple);

myHash.put("Group2", myList);
```

When I view the results on the emulator it displays Orange and Apple for both groups.  Any suggestions would be appreciated since I don't program in java often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myList.add("Carrot"); myList.add("Cabbage");

myHash.put("Group1", myList); 

//replace clear to new object.

myList = new ArrayList();

myList.add("Orange"); myList.add("Apple);

myHash.put("Group2", myList);
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Is this the only way of doing this or are there other methods that you know of? I'm just curious.

Comment: for the logic u have written. yes, only one way